# Hankel operator with symbol a Blaschke product

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, operator-theory

If $B={\prod}_j \varphi_j$ is a Blaschke product (finite or infinite) of Blaschke factors $\varphi_j(w)=\frac{w-\alpha_j}{1-\overline{\alpha_j}w}$ with $|\alpha_j|>1$, is it true that the norm of the Hankel operator (in Hardy spaces on the unit disk) $\Vert H_B\Vert$ is equal to one?

I think I have proved it for a Blaschke factor but I do not see how to generalize it (if it is possible).

Comment: To produce the double bar needed for typing norms, use `\|` instead of the uglier `||`.

Comment: This seems to be the same (or at least very similar) to your question on math.SE: [Hankel operator with symbol a Blaschke product](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2469360).

Comment: Humans make mystakes... I am not used to this website. What's your point?